# Why doesn't Keras' ModelCheckPoint save my best model with the highest validation accuracy during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, conv-neural-network

I am training a ResNet18 with Keras. As shown below, I used ModelCheckPoint to save the best model based on the validation accuracy.

```
model = ResNet18(2)
model.build(input_shape = (None,128,128,3))

model.summary()
model.save_weights('./Adam_resnet18_original.hdf5')
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('Adam_resnet18_weights.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max')

batch_size = 128
model.fit(generator(batch_size, x_train, y_train), steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) // batch_size, validation_data = generator(batch_size, x_valid, y_valid), validation_steps = len(x_valid) // batch_size, callbacks=[mcp_save], epochs = 300)
```

As shown in the picture below, the validation accuracy could go up to 0.8281 during training.
[Training History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmDAn.png)

However, when I used the final model to get the final validation accuracy with the code below, I got an accuracy that's only 0.78109. Can anybody enlighten me what might be the problem here? Thanks a lot!

```
model.load_weights('Adam_resnet18_weights.hdf5')

predictions_validation = model.predict(generator(batch_size, x_valid, y_valid), steps = len(x_valid) // batch_size + 1)
predictions_validation_label = np.argmax(predictions_validation, axis=1)
Y_valid_label = np.argmax(Y_valid, axis=1)
accuracy_validation_conventional = accuracy_score(Y_valid_label, predictions_validation_label[:len(Y_valid_label)])
print(f'Accuracy on the validation set: {accuracy_validation_conventional}')
```

Comment: Notice that the training accuracy stays at 100% and training loss oscillating wildly, your model seems overfitting. Review your training data, try decreasing learning rate and/or other configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the model is overfitting. My main question is why would the final validation accuracy be lower than the validation accuracy during training given that I used the ModelCheckPoint callback to save the best model (based on the validation accuracy). My understanding is that Keras would save the model when the validation accuracy is 0.8281 and that won't be overwritten by the results in the later epochs since the validation accuracy didn't exceed 0.8281.

Comment: I see. For this question, 3 things may go wrong: 1. data 2. model 3. validation script

Comment: So I would begin by checking validation data - are they really consistent during training and validation stage? A quick test could be printing out total # of counts of all category.

Comment: Second is the model. Make sure the model you saved is identical to the one loaded afterwards. E.g. keep an in-memory copy of the best model, and save&load the written model to compare.

Comment: Third is the validation function. Chances are the codes to compute validation score during and after training are not consistent. Try writing out the raw outputs from model during and after training (without any calculations e.g. `.argmax()`) and compare. If the two output are identical, then the problem lies in how the scores are computed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I found the bug. Since I am using a data generator for the validation data during training, if I don't set the batch size to a divisible number of the number of validation data, there will be some validation data left out during training. That's where the mismatch in the accuracies comes from. Thanks again for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest clue here is that the accuracy is stuck to 1.000 for the last couple epochs. From this, it appears that this model is overfitting. An intuitive understanding of overfitting would be like a student taking the exact same test over and over again, to the point where they just memorize the answers to each question and are unable to adapt to small changes in wording. The net has "memorized" the training data but is unable to adapt to the testing data.

It's a little tricky to figure out what the best approach would be since I don't know the size of the dataset you are working with or the details of the model. I am under the assumption that the dataset is of a decent size (if not, try [data augmentation](https://nanonets.com/blog/data-augmentation-how-to-use-deep-learning-when-you-have-limited-data-part-2/)) and you have defined a multi-layered net (if you are importing this model from Keras, your options may be a little more limited). Here are some suggestions though:

1. Stop earlier. Set your ephochs to be a smaller number to prevent overtraining. This is the simplest and easiest solution, and it would make sense in your case since accuracy is already at 1.00 for the last several epochs. If you are able to graph your accuracy and loss over time, this will help as you will be able to visually pinpoint the number of epochs where overfitting begins, as you can see in [this example](https://1.cms.s81c.com/sites/default/files/2021-03-03/classic%20overfitting_0.jpg). There are fancier ways to implement early stopping, but simply running for fewer epochs will probably be sufficient for your purposes.
2. Add [dropout layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/). Put simply, this will "turn off" random weights in the network, which prevents the network from over-relying on a small subset of nodes. This is also a common technique to prevent overfitting.

A fuller explanation along with other suggestions can be found [here](https://www.v7labs.com/blog/overfitting). Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the model is overfitting. My main question is why would the final validation accuracy be lower than the validation accuracy during training given that I used the ModelCheckPoint callback to save the best model (based on the validation accuracy). My understanding is that Keras would save the model when the validation accuracy is 0.8281 and that won't be overwritten by the results in the later epochs since the validation accuracy didn't exceed 0.8281.

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if this is not the case, but it seems like the validation data is re-shuffled after you’re loading in the net weights. If that’s the case, you are indeed using the exact same model that produced the 0.82, but since the data is different it will not produce the exact same results.

Comment: I did pass the same validation set to model.fit() and model.predict(), where the validation set is prepared at the very beginning of my code with train_test_split(). The order within the validation set might be shuffled indeed, but, to my understanding, I don’t think it would affect the result of the accuracy, would it?

Comment: You’re correct, the order shouldn’t matter. Are you deleting this file before each run? If not, it might be an old model that happened to have a high validation accuracy with a different train test split. If thats not the case here, for a bit of debugging information, could you check if the accuracy is the same if you make two back-to-back calls to predict?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I found the bug. Since I am using a data generator for the validation data during training, if I don't set the batch size to a divisible number of the number of validation data, there will be some validation data left out during training. That's where the mismatch in the accuracies comes from. Thanks again for your answers!